# Custom property hops{}

Tags: python, objects, add-on, properties

Blender 2.78c adds an object custom property hops{} which is labeled "API Defin" - can't be edited, won't stay deleted, can't find docs on it. Anyone know what it is and if it's documented somewhere?

Comment: Did you try disabling addons and see if it is from one of them?

Comment: Brilliant! Didn't think of that - yes, it is something that the hardops add-on is adding. Mystery solved - thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Great! I have added my comment as an answer to your question with some additional information. You could accept it if you think that it is appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can debug this issue by disabling addons and see if it is from one of them?

Blender Python API allows addons to register properties on some of the builtin types when the addon is enabled. These properties are attached to builtin types in the addon register function and detached in the unregister function.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it is something that the Hardops add-on is adding. Mystery solved.